# how can i create a Query to position the percentage if the class have 3 students

Tags: mysql

how can i create a Query to position the percentage if the class have 3 students with the percentage number to position them in a same number e.g Marks got 88%, smart got 85%, Mute got 85%, Martin got 82%, David got 76% and Mary got 62. therefore, i want Mark be in number 1, smart and Mute be the number 2 and Martin to be number 3, David to be number 4.
Illustrations should be like;

```
1= Marks`enter code here`
2= Mute`enter code here`
2= Smart`enter code here`
3= Martin`enter code here`
4= David`enter code here`
5= Mary`enter code here`
```

Using Structure query language (Mysql). help me please with the query

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
Also see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query for SQL related questions.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a dense_rank function. If you are using mySql 8.0 or higher you may use -

```
SELECT STUD_NAME,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY MARKS) RANK
  FROM YOUR_TABLE;
```